# Допустимо ли использование мата в никнеймах пользователей?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, профиль-участника

В последнее время стал замечать никнеймы подобные этому: [satisFUCKtor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/19376/satisfucktor)

Использование мата в никнейме абсолютно очевидно, поскольку пользователь сам выделил его в капсом.

Что будет делать администрация с такими пользователями? Соль в том, что я не нашел ограничений накладываемых на никнеймы участников сети.

Я предлагаю принудительное переименование, если это уже не предусмотрено правилами ресурса.

Comment: Хм. Вот в этом [обсуждении на meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204575/154101) говорится, что "you can't have clearly offensive username (swearing, hate speech, etc.), and you can't impersonate someone who might reasonably be expected to be an actual user of the site" — а в остальном всё в порядке. Обсуждаемый ник по идее подпадает под swearing.

Comment: Хотя я в общем не вижу ничего особого. Ну неприличное слово, подумаешь. Человек не нашёл, чем бы другим выделиться.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Подобные имена пользователей недопустимы. В случае обнаружения пользователей с подобными именами, пожалуйста, сообщайте администрации. Скорее всего, мы просто изменим имя. Если в будущем пользователь снова выберет некультурное имя, будем блокировать доступ к учётной записи.