# Определение адекватности ника (модерация) - есть ли какие-то меры?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, профиль-участника

Итак господа, я тут нахожусь довольно давно и видел много новых "лиц". Но сегодня меня привлек новый вопрос, вернее не сам вопрос сколько ник [ТС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/407790/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%A1%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю есть ли у нас меры для определения адекватности и допустимости ника. Я пометил тревогой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197999/process-unexpectedly-exit-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-android-studio-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) который был задан данным любителем чистых подъездов. Но моя тревога все еще не рассмотрена (может выходные и все такое) и я решил спросить тут в целом правильно ли я вообще понимаю данную ситуацию. Так же я не уверен что можно вообще что-либо сделать в данном случае, кроме как попросить в комментариях изменить ник. Конечно администрация данного ресурса даёт некую свободу в именовании юзера, но мне кажется должны быть рамки приличия хотя-бы элементарные. В данном случае меня смущают некоторые вещи:

1. лексика которую использовали для описания процесса загрязнения подъездов
2. плохой пример для будущих поколений - через несколько лет мы рискуем увидеть много поборников чистоты и всего прочего в списках пользователей

Как мне кажется данный ник полностью **недопустим**, но это мое мнение :) Если это ок, то я буду учитывать в будущем позицию сообщества. Тут я видел только [вопрос по поводу аватара](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9908/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8). Если же все-таки это недопустимо и нет никакой модерации (хотя-бы автоматической) ника, то предлагаю создать (либо забить).

Comment: кажется я его где-то уже видел...

Comment: А вот создать это хорошо, я как раз бота делаю.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, бота для SO или где-то у себя? В любом случае мне кажется такое отслеживать очень желательно :)

Comment: для нашего SO...

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115560/bots-on-ru-so

Comment: Да, какая-то проверка на адекватность юзера (и удаление его) не помешала бы

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, тогда я всеми конечностями за :) Вы делаете хорошее дело и я надеюсь у вас все получится :)

Comment: @avp, ну удалять сразу я думаю не стоит )) можно предупредить или что-то типа того, а когда пользователь игнорит то после последнего китайского удалять :)

Comment: @Andrew Если меня на забанят до егого момента ;) А то я добавил функцию контроля над учеткой бота, а тут есть недовольные. Надо с Николасом поговорить, я его позвал, а его пока нет тут.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, я не знаю насколько остро стоит тут данная тема, но мне такой ник как-то не заходит) обложились кучей правил для публикации вопросов, а на пользователя не смотрим :)

Comment: @Andrew Тоже так считаю. SmokeDetector ищет вопросы и ответы, а на комменты с пользователями не смотрит.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, сообщество эволюционирует потихоньку, я думаю администрация знает про проблемы и решает по возможности :)

Comment: Может и не дубликат, но точно по связанной теме: [Допустимо ли использование мата в никнеймах пользователей?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/212/176217)

Comment: Справедливости ради надо заметить, что в этом нике нет ни расовой, ни политической составляющей.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, почему вы так считаете? я исходил из того что обама политик и афроамериканец)) возможно я ошибся не спорю, но это не уменьшает недопустимости ника в пределах этого форума)

Comment: @Andrew то, что кто-то политик и афроамериканец, ещё не значит, что всё сказанное о нём имеет политический или расовый посыл.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в ваших словах есть смысл и я не могу не согласится) может в момент формирования данного вопроса меня бомбило от самой адекватности ника и туда затесалась данная причина :) спасибо за указание на проблему в формулировке

Comment: Ник несет негативно-политически-мемный смысл. Да, напрямую ничего такого нет, но это называется подстрекательство. У особо рьяных людей может вызвать взрыв пятой точки.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Как модератор, я за подобные ники однозначно присуждаю недельный бан. При этом, я сам лично не инициирую бан, а реагирую на тревоги выставляемые неравнодушными юзерами.

Фактически наличие тревог это есть ответ на вопрос о мере адекватности ников - если я вижу, что тревоги есть и тревога созвучна моей личной тревоге, то я баню. Стараюсь без необходимости не злоупотреблять своими полномочиями. В теории наверное возможен вариант, что юзер выставит тревогу, и я как модератор не буду разделять тревогу - да, так бывает. Но пока со спорными никами таких коллизий еще не было.

Кроме [ОбамаХватитСсатьВПодъездах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/407790/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%a5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%a1%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%92%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%85) были аналогично вознаграждены банами еще и:

- [SiskiPizdaPiski](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/412811/siskipizdapiski)
- [Еблан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/413023/user413023)

это те что приходят в голову, были и другие.

Если после недельного бана юзер не исправляется, то аккаунт удаляется.

Comment: первый юзер из вашего списка все еще активен насколько я вижу, либо разлочился по истечению срока :)

Comment: Он сегодня только разлочился. Посмотрим за его активностью. Если не поменяет ник - выставьте на него тревогу дальше решим

Comment: вот немного непонятно с тревогам по юзеру, напрямую на юзера тревогу нельзя скинуть насколько я знаю, тогда получается тревогу на коммент либо на вопрос нужно давать?

Comment: Да, как то так. Тревогу на вопрос/комментарий

Comment: А почему ник не сбросить (как делается в связанном вопросе) совместно с предупреждением вместо бана?

Comment: Согласен, сбросил ник у означенного товарища

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/414276/error-%d0%a5%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: @VictorVosMottor будет тревога на ник юзера, отреагирую, если нет, значит нет...

Comment: @Barmaley Тревогу что ли поднять, только у него нет ни одного сообщения (

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/413828/kirill-shvedov

Comment: @VictorVosMottor а что с ним не так?

Comment: @Barmaley оскорбления может содержать не только имя, но и аватар... раз уж на то пошло ;)

Comment: Все уже придумано! кто узнал цитату? "Примечание: во избежание имперсонаций, злоупотреблений и диффамаций запрещается присваивать указанным живым существам имена широко известных деятелей истории, литературы и искусства"

Answer (score 1):

Довольно много таких было/есть. Будь я модератор, я бы отправлял "Это сообщение касается вашей учетной записи на StackOverflow" и там говорил, что мол так называться не стоит, может стоит выбрать что-то менее вызывающее ;).

По-поводу же "сделать" я бы с радостью т.к. делаю своего бота, и были у меня уже такие идеи, но что точно ловит не понятно.
Ежели кто мне предложить регекс или хоть идею для него, то буду отслеживать.

Comment: Боту (если он не уровня IBM Watson) такое вряд ли доступно

Comment: @avp Зря так думаете.

Comment: но я ведь правильно понимаю что на самого пользователя мы никак не можем повлиять, кроме как написать ему?

Comment: @Andrew Ну вроде да.

Comment: @Andrew, ещё можно сбросить ник. Ему уже написали.